# Inverse Stieltjes transform alternate form

Tags: complex-analysis

Im reading through Robert Sips 1948 paper 'On the Structure of a Catalyst Surface' and I came to this statement of the inverse Stieltjes transform:

[image: Inverse Stieltjes from (Sips, 1948)]

I'm not sure how equation (6) is derived from equation (5). I apologize if this is a basic question, but I'd like some help.

Comment: Part of equation 5 is missing.  Is the LHS of equation 5 the same as the LHS of equation 6, i.e., just $\varphi(x)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've answered my own question, here it is formally:

[image]